# Getting "KeyError:" when trying to retrieve the key value from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

My function "getint" returns below values:

response: 0
  id: 70402
  type: 1
  has value
  int value: 15

I have stored the above value in String s and written below code to print the  'int value' data 15.

Code:

```
s= '''response: 0
      id: 70402
      type: 1
      has value
      int value: 15
   '''

s=s.replace("has","has:")
s = s.strip()
print s
d = {}
for i in s.split('\n'):
    try:
        key, val = i.split(":")
        d[key.strip()] = val.strip()
        print d['int value']
    except ValueError:
        print "no key:value pair found in", i
```

In Output getting `KeyError:'int value'`.

Output :

> ```
>   response: 0
>   id: 70402
>   type: 1
>   has: value
>   int value: 15 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/tests/test_lang.py", line 18, in <module>
> print d['int value'] KeyError: 'int value'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. Try the below.

```
for i in s.split('\n'):
    key, val = i.split(":")
    d[key.strip()] = val.strip()

try:
    print(d['int value'])
except KeyError:
    print("no 'int value' found in", d)
```

**Explanation**

1. Use `KeyError` to catch key errors.
2. Only use `try` / `except` on the part of the code where you are trying to catch an error.
3. Unless you have a specific reason, you can as above check for the key after the dictionary is created.

Answer (score 1):

Your error because when you go through the `s tring`. Your first `i: response = 0`
but you `print d['int value']` which `d` doesn't has at that time. This will work:

```
s= '''response: 0
  id: 70402
  type: 1
  has value
  int value: 15
'''

s=s.replace("has","has:")
s = s.strip()
print s
d = {}
for i in s.split('\n'):
    try:
        key, val = i.split(":")
        d[key.strip()] = val.strip()
    except ValueError:
        print "no key:value pair found in", i
print d['int value']
```

If you want to get the error with the key. You should add:

```
except KeyError:
    print "key error found in", i
```

Or just change `ValueError` to `KeyError`

Comment: The only answer which expains what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Write `print d['int value']` out side for loop

```
s= '''response: 0
      id: 70402
      type: 1
      has value
      int value: 15
   '''

s=s.replace("has","has:")

s = s.strip()
print s
d = {}
for i in s.split('\n'):
    try:
        key, val = i.split(":")
        d[key.strip()] = val.strip()

    except ValueError:
        print "no key:value pair found in", i
print d['int value']
```